# laravel : insert or update record when exists using DB facade

Tags: laravel

is there any method for inserting new record or update when record exists in database using `DB` facade ?
Note: there is no `model` but only a `controller` , so using model related methods is impossible.my question is regards to [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to look into your database's syntax for *upserting*. It will be different depending on the database and the specific situation, and may require defining a `UNIQUE` key of some kind.

Here is an example for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

By the way, the more idiomatic approach would be to define a model. Model's allow you to handle this situation more gracefully and (in many cases) prevent you from tying your code to a specific RDBMS.

Comment: thanks, maybe  i should take your  advice and use   `model`